# Show that if $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite collection, then $\{\text{cl} (A)\ :\ A \in \mathscr{A}\}$ is locally finite too

Tags: general-topology

A collection $\mathscr{A}$ is said to be locally finite if every point has a neighborhood $V$ such as $\{ A \in \mathscr{A} : V \cap A \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite. Show that if $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite collection, then $\{ \text{cl}(A) : A \in \mathscr{A} \} $ is locally finite too, and $ \text{cl} \big(\bigcup \mathscr{A}\big) = \bigcup \text{cl}( A) $.

So I need help with this, and don't know how to begin my proof. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite. Let $\mathscr{B}:=\{\overline{A}:A\in\mathscr{A}\}$. We show that $\mathscr{B}$ is locally finite. Given a point $x$, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ intersecting only finitely many elements of $\mathscr{A}$. We claim that $U$ can only intersect finitely many elements in $\mathscr{B}$. For suppose $U\cap\overline{A}\not=\emptyset$ for some $A\in\mathscr{A}$. Then, $U\cap A\not=\emptyset$. Indeed, if $y\in U\cap \overline{A}$, then since $y\in\overline{A}$, each open set containing $y$ must have non-empty intersection with $A$; i.e., $U\cap A\not=\emptyset$. But then, since $U$ intersects only finitely many elements in $\mathscr{A}$, $U$ can intersect only finitely many elements in $\mathscr{B}$ (the closures of the sets it intersected from $\mathscr{A}$).

Next, we'll show that $\overline{Y}=\bigcup_{a\in\mathscr{A}}\overline{A}$, where $Y=\bigcup_{a\in\mathscr{A}}A$. It should be clear that $\overline{Y}\supseteq\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr{A}}\overline{A}$. Conversely, suppose $x\in\overline{Y}$. Since $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite, there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ intersecting finitely many  $A_{1},\ldots,A_{k}$ of the sets in $\mathscr{A}$. Suppose that $x\notin \overline{A_{i}}$ for any $1\leq i \leq k$. Then, $x\in U\setminus(\overline{A_{1}}\cup\cdots\cup \overline{A_{k}})$, which is open and doesn't intersect any of the sets in $\mathscr{A}$. This contradicts that $x\in\overline{Y}$. Therefore, it must be that $x\in\overline{A_{i}}$ for some $1\leq i\leq k$. Hence, $x\in\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr{A}}\overline{A}$, proving the reverse inclusion.